# How to press enter key if the input is hidden?

Tags: input, hidden, imacros, enter

I have some porblem with the iMacros coding. I would like to write a macro to comment posts in social media. I do not have any problem with the easy part, go to page, tag the textarea and write a content. This is ok. However there is no post, or comment, or send or any button to enter the text I want to comment. I tried DS but th version I have can't handle that. I just can't believe that this is so difficult to comment something if there is no button for it. I copy the html part:[this is the html part of the story](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhIPF.png)

So I hope you can help me to find out how to generate a hidden input keypress ENTER for me :) THX!

Comment: If you're using iMacros add-on for Firefox, try to record the macro in Experimental event recording mode.

Comment: Can you write me the iMacros code for this?

Comment: EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#comment_text" CHARS="nice"
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY" KEY=13

Comment: However I got this error message: RuntimeError: Element TEXTAREA is not visible, line 3 (Error code: -921)

Comment: Does all your code consist of these two lines? First of all you have to record a click event in order to expand the comment textarea.